# get all file names in subdirectories

Tags: files, find, directory, terminfo

I need to get all file names, not including the paths eg `file1` is correct and `./folder/file1` is incorrect, from subdirectories. My use case is retrieving all available terminfo file names which are located inside `/usr/share/terminfo` directory. But they are located inside another set of subdirectories as follows -

```
terminfo ア ls
1  3  5  7  9  A  c  e  f  h  j  l  m  n  o  P  Q  s  u  w  X
2  4  6  8  a  b  d  E  g  i  k  L  M  N  p  q  r  t  v  x  z

terminfo ア cd 1
1 ア ls
1178  1730-lm
```

You can see files are located inside these `1` `3` or `A` subdirectories and I need all file names from each subdirectories. There are a total of `42 directories, 2720 files` so manual process would be exhausting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find /usr/share/terminfo -type f -exec basename {} \;`

Comment: `find /usr/share/terminfo -type f -exec basename {} \; | wc -l` gives `2718` while `tree` reports `42 directories, 2720 files`..

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I can't reproduce that discrepancy.

Comment: `[usr@server terminfo]$ tree | tail -n 1
21 directories, 119 files
[usr@server terminfo]$ find /usr/share/terminfo -type f -exec basename {} \; | wc -l
119`

Comment: okay my VM doesn't shows this as well, only happens on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Since we know that the files we'd like to have the names of are two levels under `/usr/share/terminfo`, and that there are no further directories beneath that, this would be a fast solution (only executes `find` and `cut` once):

```
$ find /usr/share/terminfo -type f | cut -d '/' -f 6
```

Alternatively, with one slightly "heavier" `sed` substitution:

```
$ find /usr/share/terminfo -type f | sed 's#^.*/##'
```

The `sed` substitution removes everything up to and including the last `/` of each line of output from `find`.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1 Using **tree**

(man tree for details)

```
tree -i /usr/shar/terminfo
```

or if you want do remove the directories:

```
tree -iF /usr/shar/terminfo | grep -v /
```

#### 2 Using **ls**

```
ls -R /usr/share/terminfo  | grep -v /
```

```
ls /usr/share/terminfo/*/* | grep -o '[^/]*$'
```

```
basename -a $(ls /usr/share/terminfo/*/*)
```